# How to handle unexpected huge traffic for ecommerce website on specific days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, performance, load-balancing, monitoring

We are developing an ecommerce website, right now we have 2 dedicated web server and 1 dedicated db server. We have load balancer behind this 2 web servers. right now everything is working fine as we have specific amount of user which logs in daily and our current setup we don't face any performance issues.

On festival seasons there will be some promotion and offers are going on, at this time we may face huge traffic on website. How to handle this scenario?

Are there any specific tools available to handle this scenario? Is AWS or Azure has any features on provision for this? Is their any different technic we can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use Autoscaling?

Comment: Yes autoscaling is the feature available from AWS to scale up and down your infrastructure based on various parameters..

Comment: No Marcin we are not using AutoScaling. Chetan thanks for sharing. Is there any other tools?

Comment: If you are using AWS then autoscaling is the most convenient option. Why you would not want to use it?

Comment: Maybe, you want an [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-overview) service to preload or efficiently deliver web content to users when the huge traffic comes.?

Comment: Will check on this as well Nancy, Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure Autoscale](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/autoscale/) would just be perfect for this scenario.

Autoscale in Azure is a built-in feature of Cloud Services, Mobile Services, Virtual Machine Scale Sets and Websites that helps applications perform their best when demand changes. Of course, performance means different things for different applications. Some apps are CPU-bound, others memory-bound.

Autoscale allows you to add resources to handle increases in load and also save money by removing resources that are sitting idle. You specify a minimum and maximum number of instances to run and add or remove VMs automatically based on a set of rules.

Having a minimum makes sure your application is always running even under no load. Having a maximum limits your total possible hourly cost. You automatically scale between these two extremes using rules you create, as shown below:

[image: Autoscale in Microsoft Azure]

Taking your example, since your application might need to handle spikes in requests during certain parts of the year, Autoscale can scale your service by any built-in platform metric, or by a custom metric you define, to meet the increased demand.

This would give you the ability to use as much capacity as you need, scaling out as load increases, and scaling in when the extra capacity is not needed, all happening automatically.

Here are some additional resources that explain more about the available options in Azure, along with best practices, and application design considerations for your reference:

- [Azure Monitor autoscale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-overview)
- [Walkthrough - Get started with Autoscale in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started)
- [Overview of common autoscale patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-common-scale-patterns)
- [Autoscale Recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/design-principles/scale-out)
- [Best practices - Autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/auto-scaling)

In addition to configuring autoscaling, you can also evaluate implementing a caching strategy with [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/) as @Nancy mentioned above, to efficiently deliver web content to your users and minimize latency.